# Maximum Principle variation.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

> Let $f$ be a non-constant holomorphic function in a bounded open connected set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $M:=\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |f(z_n)|$  for every sequence ${z_n}$ in $\Omega$ which converges to a boundary point of $\Omega$. Show that $|f(z)|<M$ for $z\in \Omega$.

I think this problem is another version of Maximum principle.
But I can't catch the hint to solve.
Could you give me  some hint?

Comment: What is $f$? Holomorphic and non-constant I assume?

Comment: sorry I will edit

Comment: @user1952009 We're not in the unit disc.

Comment: @zhw. : right, then $g(\epsilon) = \sup_{d(z,\partial \Omega) > \epsilon} |f(z)|$ where $d(z,\partial \Omega) = \min_{s\in \partial \Omega} |z-s|$